Calculating an If/Then Based on Certain Criteria in a Column
I'm trying to write the final part of my formula to calculate grade reductions based on absences.  As you can see in the table below, I can write a calculation that adds up the number of days missed by hour, and that works fine going vertically, but is there a way to calculate this horizontally?
EX: Hour 6 (B3 & B4 ) has a total of 5 absence days (F3+F4).  This is represented in Hour 6 in K3 and K4.  Then, Hour 5 has 4 total absences calculated out in L5 & L6.  Is there a way to search the entire record for John Doe so that all the absences go horizontally?  So basically, K3 would be 5, L3 would be 4, M3 would be 2.
I'm using this formula currently to calculate in L3, but that only works when I'm matching vertically.  =IF(AND(B3=5, J3>2), 100-(J3*5),""  **This formula is also calculating that 3 or more absences are losing 5 points per absence (3 absences would be 15 points)...so it won't show "3" for the days missed, it would show 85, because that's how many points are left out of 100.

=IF(AND(($B$3:$B$1801=4),($J$3:$J$1801>2)),100-($J$3:$J$1801*5),"")
However that does not yield any results.
Hoping someone can help.  Thanks in advance!

If you are using M365 you should have access to the PIVOTBY function, which makes things easier:
=PIVOTBY(A2:A14,B2:B14,F2:F14,LAMBDA(x,100-IF(SUM(x)>2,SUM(x)-2,0)*5),,0,,0,-1)


The first argument from Column A are the rows (the names).
The second argument from Column B are the columns (the Hour).
The third argument from column F are the values (Days).
The fourth argument is a function that calculates:
100 minus, if there are more than 2 days absent, 5 times each day from 3 onwards
The arguments of zero in positions 6 and 8 indicate that we don't want to output row or column totals (change them if you do).
The last argument -1 tells the function to sort the Days in descending order.

This is the result:


I have m365, but I access Excel via the web.  We have the business/education version, by any chance do you know if the "pivotby" feature will work online, or only on the desktop version?

It's not available in Excel for Web at the moment, but I think it should be soon. I'm trying to find more details for you.

The AND function is an aggregate function and always returns only one result. Therefore, it cannot be used in this way in array calculations. Multiplication should be used instead:
=IF(($B$3:$B$1801=4)*($J$3:$J$1801>2), 100-$J$3:$J$1801*5, "")

Logical values in multiplication (and in other arithmetic operations) are converted into numbers:
TRUE = 1, FALSE = 0
In place of 4, you can insert a horizontal array constant e.g.,{6,5,4,3,2,1} to stretch the results horizontally.

If you have Excel for Microsoft 365, you could try this:
Enter in K2:

in grade_for_student, for each hour specified in the hours header, calculate the grades with 100 - 5 * SUMIFS(days_, name, n, hour_, h)
in grades, go through each name, and if it is the first row first row for the name, get the grades

=LET(d, A2:F14, name, INDEX(d, , 1), hour_, INDEX(d, , 2), days_, INDEX(d, , 6),
    for_hours, K1:P1,
    grade_for_student, LAMBDA(n, MAP(--SUBSTITUTE(for_hours, "Hour ", ""),
            LAMBDA(h, 100 - 5 * SUMIFS(days_, name, n, hour_, h)))),
    name_idx, XMATCH(name, UNIQUE(name)),
    first_row_for_name, DROP(FREQUENCY(name_idx, name_idx), -1) <> 0,
    grades, REDUCE("", SEQUENCE(ROWS(name)), LAMBDA(acc,i,
            VSTACK(acc, IF(INDEX(first_row_for_name, i, 1), grade_for_student(INDEX(name, i, 1)),"")))),
    IFNA(DROP(grades, 1), ""))


for grade reduction if the number of days missed is 3 or higher:
=LET(
  d, A2:F14, name, INDEX(d, , 1), hour_, INDEX(d, , 2), days_, INDEX(d, , 6),
  for_hours, K1:P1,
  grade_for_student, LAMBDA(n,
    MAP(
      --SUBSTITUTE(for_hours, "Hour ", ""),
      LAMBDA(h,
        LET(
          absent_days, SUMIFS(days_, name, n, hour_, h),
          100 - 5 * (absent_days > 2) * absent_days)))),
  name_idx, XMATCH(name, UNIQUE(name)),
  first_row_for_name, DROP(FREQUENCY(name_idx, name_idx), -1) <> 0,
  grades, REDUCE("", SEQUENCE(ROWS(name)),
    LAMBDA(acc, i,
        VSTACK(acc, IF(INDEX(first_row_for_name, i, 1), grade_for_student(INDEX(name, i, 1)), "")))),
  IFNA(DROP(grades, 1), "")
)




Thank you!  I got that to work, my only question is: Is there a way to modify this function so that it will only calculate the grade reduction if the number of days missed is 3 or higher?  So if they had 0,1,2 absences, it would not calculate and still show 100?  I'm trying to figure out where to insert a ">2" statement, but I'm not having much success.

@Hunter1979, I've updated the answer. Please let me know if it works satisfactorily.
